# Permission denied on /system/xbin/su when trying to unroot Sony Xperia L

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rooting, root-access, permissions

I'm trying to root my Sony XPeria L reading [this tutorial](http://theunlockr.com/2013/09/14/how-to-root-the-xperia-l/) The firmaware is 15.0.А.2.17, model C2105, and my Android version est 4.1.2

Everything was good until step 9, where I get the following error :
`/system/bin/sh: /system/xbin/su: Permission denied`

So I ran adb.exe from my computer and try to grant my permissions on this file. I tried some `chmod 777 su` but this is a "Read-only file system"...

I'm a C# developper and I always used Windows, so Android world is totally new for me. Can anyone help me to avoid this error message ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

You have to remount read-only partitions with a permission of read and write first.

```
# mount -o rw,remount /
# mount -o rw,remount /system
```

Now, you can do anything.